# What is Windows 8 syncing, specifically?

Tags: windows-8, sync

In the Windows 8 Settings app, there's a *Sync* section that lets you sync Windows and app settings across multiple Windows 8 computers. It doesn't give very fine-grain control, however, and is even somewhat ambiguous about what each setting is enabling/disabling (it uses the words "and more" implying that there's some other unnamed settings that it will sync).

I had to disable syncing on my desktop completely because it was causing certain settings and even my music library (which I manage on SkyDrive manually) to be affected in ways I didn't like.

I was wondering if there was a more detailed, comprehensive list of what is in each category of sync, and also if there is a way to enable/disable syncing of each individual item instead of syncing each broad category.

I'm referring to this, by the way:
[image: screenshot of Settings app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a Microsoft representative/moderator on technet there [aren't any official documents or details out on that](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w8itprogeneral/thread/549acbe2-0e25-403e-adac-c222fa864826), at least yet. Hopefully in time there will be someone who investigates or Microsoft releases details about this.